# SQL, Group by one column with one distinct column

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, distinct

I have a table with following structure

```
id  phone_number  message    schedule_id
1 | 1212121212  | aaaaa |    12
2 | 2323232323  | bbbbb |    12
3 | 1212121212  | ccccc |    12
4 | 1212121212  | ddddd |    13
```

I want to fetch a row with same phone_number and different schedule_id
I use the following query to fetch rows with same phone number

```
select * from message group by to_number having count(*)>1;
```

But it groups the rows with different schedule_id also

Can anybody help me to write the query ?

Comment: What is your expected output

Comment: Which MySQL version are you using?

Comment: @ErayBalkanli i got it using the query in answer

Comment: How can one row have a "different schedule_id"?  There is only one schedule_id per row.

Comment: Never. I mean same phone number with different schedule_id s. There may be different schedules with same phone number

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `EXISTS` :

```
select m.*
from message m
where exists (select 1 from message m1 where m1.to_number = m.to_number and m1.id <> m.id);
```

You can also use `GROUP BY`, just include that column also :

```
select to_number, schedule_id 
from message 
group by to_number, schedule_id 
having count(*) > 1;
```

Comment: Thanks brother. Got it

Comment: @Strawberry. . . That was typo.

Answer (score 1):

You should use a join for teh subqselect with count  group by phone_number

```
  select m.* 
  from  message m
  inner join (
        select phone_number
        from message 
        group by phone_number
        having count(*)>1;

  ) t on t.phone_number  = m.phone_number
```

Comment: group by _phone_number_

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are expecting?

```
select distinct phone_number, schedule_id from message;
```